# cellPadding esta moviendo mi texto a la izquierda

Tags: html, table

La propiedad cellpadding esta desalineando mi texto y lo recorre a la izquierda mientras más lo agrando más se mueve, quiero saber como hacer mi celda grande con mi texto alineado al centro.

```
<style>
           
                th, td{
                    font-size: 7.8px;
                    text-align: center;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    
                }
            
            </style>
            <table cellpadding="11" cellspacing="0">
                <tr nobr="true">
                    <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td>
                    <td colspan="12">DATO 1</td>
                    <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td>
                    <td colspan="4">DATO 1</td>
                    <td colspan="3">DATO 1</td>
                    <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
```

[image: tabla]

Comment: No entiendo el problema, el texto está al centro con `text-align: center;`

Comment: Mientras más padding se mueve más a la izquierda, como se puede ver en la celda 5

Comment: Ya no tiene espacio para poner el texto, por eso lo mueve.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad cellpadding controla el espacio entre el contenido de la celda y los bordes de la celda. En tu caso, esto está afectando la alineación del texto en las celdas.

Para lograr que el texto se alinee al centro y que las celdas tengan un tamaño adecuado, te recomiendo utilizar estilos CSS para manejar el espaciado y la alineación en lugar de depender de cellpadding. Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código que utiliza CSS para lograr el efecto deseado:

```html
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    th, td {
        font-size: 7.8px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px; /* Espaciado interno de las celdas */
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td>
        <td colspan="12">DATO 1</td>
        <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td>
        <td colspan="4">DATO 1</td>
        <td colspan="3">DATO 1</td>
        <td colspan="5">DATO 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

He eliminado la propiedad `cellpadding` y he utilizado la propiedad `padding` en el estilo CSS de las celdas (th y td) para controlar el espaciado interno de las celdas. El valor `10px` se puede ajustar según tus preferencias.

Comment: Probaste tu ejemplo, al parecer no funciona, no se alinea el texto.